# combine 4* 4 bytes values into 4 bytes and extract each value separately using one byte keys.

Tags: logic

Here's my problem ,

I have 4 * 4 bytes i.e a,b,c,d and each one is 4 bytes length 
I want to generate x = function(a,b,c,d) , where x is 4 bytes 
and generate aKey,bKey,cKey,dKey where each key is 1 byte.

so if I used function(x,aKey) i will get a ?

is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming your bytes have $8$ bits) there are $2^{32}\cdot2^{32}\cdot2^{32}\cdot2^{32} = 2^{128}$ possibilities for $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ and only $2^{32}$ possible values for $x = f(a, b, c, d)$. So the only way you can guarantee to be able to recover $a$ from $x$ is if $f(a, b, c, d)$ is independent of $b$, $c$ and $d$ (so that $f(a, b, c, d)$ gives no information at all about $b$, $c$ or $d$). So if you want to be able to extract $b$, $c$ and $d$ from $f(a, b, c, d)$ as well, there is no solution: you can't cram $128$ bits of information content into $32$ bits.

Comment: i also need function(x,bkey) to get a , and so ... for c & d